# How to Handle Incomplete Django/Nginx File Server URLs?

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django website that uses Nginx on a separate file server to serve up images uploaded by my users.  When any user views another user's photos, the link to the photo will have this structure:

```
https://fs01.mysite.com/media/photos/<username>_<photo-id>.jpg
```

When the page is rendered, the user's photo is served up by the file server (fs).  But what is the Nginx way of handling incomplete (one could also say incorrect) requests to subdirectories of the above URL?  For example, if a user enters this URL:

```
https://fs01.mysite.com
```

...they see Nginx's default "Welcome to nginx on ..." page.  If they enter this URL:

```
https://fs01.mysite.com/media
```

...they'll get the Nginx "404 Not Found" page.  And if they enter this URL:

```
https://fs01.mysite.com/media/photos
```

...they'll get the Nginx "403 Forbidden" page.

How do you handle these situations in Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

1. They see welcome page, because the nginx matches default vhost entry instead of yours. You should probably delete the default one (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, depending on the linux distribution you use) and make sure that `server_name` line matches your url (i.e. no slash at the end).
2. Looks like your `location` block matckes only `media/` (with the slash at the end). Thats why you get 404 error - it matches different `location` block and is probably handled by Django.
3. You are not allowed to list the directory, so you get the Forbidden error.

I think that it is up to you how such cases are handled, just make them consistent. Make sure that you understand nginx configuration and the pathways different requests take. To avoid 403 error, you can put empty `index.html` file in that directory.